# Eclipse Android Layout Design

Tags: android, android-layout, adt

Is there any good tutorial available to learn how to use the android layout design tool available in eclipse ADT plugin. I'm new to Android development. I'm just learning myself by dragging and dropping palette items in screen. But I'm not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The layout design tool only gets you so far. 
The best starting place is probably here;
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

Its google's own introduction to layouts.

The next stop after working through that is to google "Android Layout Tricks" The top results are gold.

For future-proofing this reply - here are the links from google:

http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/16/android-layout-tricks-4-optimize-part-2/

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-with.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html